# Changing Google Plus page URL

Tags: youtube, google-plus, google-plus-pages

I have a Google Plus business page and a brand page.
The business page has a URL of `google.com/+companyname`. I didn't choose it as a custom URL. I have another custom URL: `google.com/+companynamexyz`, but for some reason my business page can be accessed with either URL.

I want to be able to add my brand page and YouTube Chanel to use the URL of `google.com/+companyname`.

What I've tried so far:

Adding the YouTube channel to the Business page, it gets the bad URL only: `youtube.com/c/companynamexyz`. Instead I want it to be: `youtube.com/c/companyname`.

I should be able to do it since I already own the URL, however I can't. The Google Plus system is extremely complicated and I don't how to deal with it.
I'm open to try any suggestions.

Comment: You may want to try again now, YouTube's custom URL system has changed slightly since and isn't hard tied with Google+' anymore.